# Regex- Does case insensitivity only apply to letters (upper and lower case)?

Tags: regex

(Sorry I know the question sounds ridiculous) and if so which of the following is preferred:

```
[a-zA-Z]
[a-z]i
[A-Z]i
```

Comment: What else do you think case insensitivity could apply to?

Comment: I think it should work with letters in other languages too

Comment: I was thinking it may also refer to accent marks, (ex. 'à' and 'a' are the same)

Comment: @LedZeppelin: ignoring case won't make `à` and `a` the same - it'll make `à` and `À` the same, and `a` and `A` the same, but it won't make accents optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the regex engine supports Unicode and the appropriate option is passed (e.g. in PCRE, the `u` modifier), then case insensitivity is also applied to Unicode character sequences where appropriate.